# Como ligo onclick no meu javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, button, onclick

Bom, estou fazendo um jogo em javascript onde tenho 100 botões e preciso que o valor do botão que o usuário clicar seja buscado para validar se o usuário acertou ou não, me recomendaram essa função

```
function minhaFuncao(id){
var alor = documenr.getElementById(id).value()
}
```

Porém eu não faço ideia de como usá-la se são 100 valores e eu coloquei um id para cada botão. Devo colocar o mesmo id ?

Comment: Podes mostrar o HTML de um desses botões? Clica em [edit] e junta à pergunta. Nós podemos ajudar a formatar o HTML na pergunta.

Answer (score 1):

Crie todos os botões com o `class="botoes"` e `id` diferente para cada um, pois cada um deve possuir um identificador único para facilitar o acesso ao mesmo e utilize a função abaixo.
A função abaixo detectará quando qualquer botão pertencente à `classe botoes` for clicado e pegará o `id` e `value` do botão clicado:

```js
$('.botoes').click(function(){
       var id = $(this).attr('id');
       var valor = $(this).val();
       console.log ("Botão: "+ id + "  Valor: "+ valor);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="button" class="botoes" id="botão1" value="valor1" name="botão1">

<input type="button" class="botoes" id="botão2" value="valor2" name="botão2">
```

Answer (score 0):

Primeiramente `Devo colocar o mesmo id ?`: não. O id é utilizado para identificar os seus elementos html na página quando for necessário manipulá-los através do javascript por exemplo, e portanto deve ser único para cada elemento da página.

A sua função javascript tem só um detalhe que está impedindo de funcionar. Você trocou o t do document pelo r. Ela ficaria assim:

```
function minhaFuncao(id){
    var valor = document.getElementById(id).value();
}
```

Creio que só falte a validação do valor do botão, de acordo com as regras do seu jogo.

Sobre o HTML, um exemplo de como fazer o botão chamar a função passando o próprio id, seria o seguinte:

```
<button name="botao1" type="button" value="valorDoBotao1" onclick="minhaFuncao(this.id)">botão 1</button>
```

Comment: É assim mesmo que eu fiz, só não coloquei nome mas coloquei id e valor porque a partir do valor eu vou validar

Comment: @FabianaFernandes agora que eu vi que na sua função a chamada do getElementById está errada. Seria assim: `document.getElementById(id).value()`. A única questão é que você trocou o t do document pelo r. :)

Comment: Muito obrigada pela ajuda, de verdade